# Boundary of compact set $[a_1,b_1] \times [a_2,b_2]$ has measure zero?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Why is the boundary of the compact set

$$[a_1,b_1] \times [a_2,b_2]$$ measure zero?

Answer (score 2):

The boundary is the union of four line segments.  All line segments in $\mathbb{R}^2$ have measure zero.  They're measurable being closed.  How to prove most easily that their measure is zero depends on your definition of Lebesgue measure, but for example Rudin *Real and Complex Analysis* 2.19, formulas (4) and (5), let this be shown easily.

In more detail consider the line segment from $(a_1,a_2)$ to $(b_1,a_2)$.  Using formula (4) write it as $\{(x,y):a_1\le x\le b_1, a_2\le y\le a_2\}$; then formula (5) gives its measure as $(b_1-a_1)(a_2-a_2)=0$.

Comment: Bummer, you beat me to it. I posted the same thing 2 min after you. Well done!

Comment: Such things always happen.

Answer (score 1):

The boundary consists of four line segments. Any line (segment) in $\mathbb R^2$ has measure zero. Indeed, for any $\varepsilon > 0$, the $x$-axis is contained in the sets $$[-n, n,] \times \left [-\tfrac{\varepsilon}{n2^{ n +2}}, \tfrac{\varepsilon}{n2^{ n+2}} \right], \,\,\, n \in \mathbb N$$ so by subadditivity, $$\lambda(x\text{-axis}) \le \sum_{n \in \mathbb N} 2n \cdot \frac{\varepsilon}{n2^{n+1}} = \varepsilon \sum_{n \in \mathbb N} \frac 1 {2^n} = \varepsilon.$$ Since $\varepsilon$ was arbitrary, the $x$-axis has measure zero. By translation and rotation invariance of the Lebesgue measure, any line (and thus by monotonicity, any subset of a line) must also have measure zero. Hence, a union of four line segments also has measure zero.

Comment: Elaborate why you choose the sets. You answer is a bit abstract, IMO.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by abstract. On the contrary, my answer is completely constructive. To prove a set $A$ has measure zero, it suffices to prove that for arbitrary $\varepsilon > 0$, we can cover $A$ with a set whose measure is not larger than $\varepsilon$. The reason I chose those sets is because their union covers the $x$-axis and the measure of their union is bounded by $\varepsilon$. This approach seems to me to be the most natural way to prove a set has measure zero.